# Is there a dynamodb wrapper that have async/await scan/query/put/update with lambda-expression support?

Tags: asp.net-core, lambda, async-await, frameworks, amazon-dynamodb

Coming from Azure where it's pretty easy to find a tablestorage wrapper that removes cumbersome query writing and transforming them into easy to use lambda (x=>x.id == 10) like queries I am missing some guidance on a dynamodb framework that is:

- async
- .net core 2.1 compatible
- has support for lambda(The c# type, completely unrelated to aws-lambda serverless) queries and scans (also for global indexes)

I have already tried servicestacks otherwise excellent PocoDynamo as it seems to fit my DynamoDB wrapper needs perfectly except it doesn't seem to have any async methods for queries and updated/put items, just for creating tables etc.

Ideally something like pocodynamo only with async support like:

```
var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb);
db.RegisterTable<MyObject>();
await db.PutItemsAsync(listOfManyMyObjects);
var myQueryResult = await db.Query<MyObject>(x=>x.Id%2 == 0).ExecAsync();
```

Comment: I think the AWS .NET sdk has this functionality.

Comment: aws .net has async functionality but since it is seems very cumbersome do work with compared to Azure TableStorage (especially queries) I was looking for a wrapper framework to make me more productive when working with DynamoDb. Specifically among the listed requirements, I do not find lambda query expressions as part of the aws .net.

Comment: If you want to have DynamoDB perform the filter in the query/scan you would have to convert your lambda query to the equivalent dynamodb filter expression which is not always possible, and not possible as far as I know for the example of getting all even ids. Otherwise just filter the results client side with Linq.

Comment: It is possible with PocoDynamo where you first write if it's a scan or query, and then put a filter on that if you want. For example you would write  `db.Query<TableName>(x=>x.PartitionKey == 0).Filter(x=>x.MyField > 10).Exec();` Or if you want to scan you use `db.Scan<TableName>(x=>x.FieldToScan == "scan").Exec().` It is this functionality I am after, along with async operations.

Comment: You could write some extension methods on top of the AWS Sdk implementation which has async methods.

Comment: Hey Mike, that's what I intend to do if there isn't anything ready made out there. I was just looking to save some time.